# Does the Airport Extreme log MAC addresses of devices that attempt to connect?

Tags: airport, logs, security, mac-address

I recently had a burglar enter my home and take a number of items and I am chasing a long shot in catching him.  I am hoping that the burglar had a smartphone that, when he entered the home, attempted to log in to my wireless network (but didn't because the network has a password).

I have an Airport Extreme wireless router and I am hoping there is a log that I can access that would show me any MAC addresses (of the smartphone) that attempted to access the wi-fi network during a very specific window of time.  I don't know if these logs exist and if they do exist, if you can pull the MAC address for a phone. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Comment: Excellent idea, but it does not as far I know. Lets wait for others who might know the answer.

Comment: I was able to pull up the logs on the router, but unfortunately they were only for current day.  I would have needed to export the logs to have a chance to catch the guy.  Oh well, it was worth a shot.

Comment: You should put that as an answer and close this question for others to find and read. Maybe one day someone will get they hands around the neck of one of them using your method.

Comment: What would you do with the MAC address? Just see if he ever comes back?  I guess if you caught him by some other means it would add to the evidence (although not sure it would be necessary).

Answer (score 3):

I was able to pull up the logs on the router, but unfortunately they were only for current day. I would have needed to export the logs to have a chance to catch the guy. Oh well, it was worth a shot.

To do this, I needed to install the airport utility v5.6 (in addition to the v6.x that was already installed).  The newer versions don't have an advanced tab which contains the ability to view "logs and statistics."